# Show/Hide label by clicking on the tkinter button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button, label, show-hide

I want to hide the label by clicking on the button and show the same label by clicking on the same button and I want to show those labels below the clicked button. I have tried the below code but by clicking any of the button only the **collaborate** label is visible in below to button2. but I want it as if I click **button1** the "**get started**" label should appear below to button1 and if I clicked **button2** the "**collaborate**" label should appear below to button2

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

def label_hide_show():
    global hidden
    if hidden:
        label1.pack(side = "top", fill = tk.BOTH)
        hidden = False
    else:
        label1.pack_forget()
        hidden=True
            
hidden = True

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="Get Started", height=3,width=26,bg="White", fg="Black", command=label_hide_show)
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Get started")
        
btn1.pack(side = "top", fill = tk.BOTH)

btn2 = tk.Button(root, text="Collaborate", height=3,width=26,bg="White", fg="Black", command=label_hide_show)
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Collaborate")
        
btn2.pack(side = "top", fill = tk.BOTH)
```

Output of the above code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution that came to mind and seemed easy is to use a single label and just update its text based on the button clicked. So you should change your function to:

```
def label_hide_show(btn):
    global hidden
    if hidden:
        label1.config(text=btn.cget('text')) # Change text to clicked buttons text
        label1.pack(side = "top", fill = tk.BOTH)
        hidden = False
    else:
        label1.pack_forget()
        hidden=True

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="Get Started", height=3,width=26,bg="White", fg="Black", command=lambda: label_hide_show(btn1))

label1 = tk.Label(root) # Make sure to just use one of this label

btn2 = tk.Button(root, text="Collaborate", height=3,width=26,bg="White", fg="Black", command=lambda: label_hide_show(btn2))
```

This way you can get it to update with the text of the button that gets clicked.

Obviously, there are other ways too, like passing the text you want to show instead of passing the button as argument:

```
def label_hide_show(text):
    global hidden
    if hidden:
        label1.config(text=text)
        label1.pack(side = "top", fill = tk.BOTH)
        hidden = False
    else:
        label1.pack_forget()
        hidden=True

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="Get Started", height=3,width=26,bg="White", fg="Black", command=lambda: label_hide_show('Get started'))
```

The use of this method is, you can use/pass ANY text other than the buttons text. Other variations of this methods include using a `StringVar()` and calling `set()` on it to change the text of label, essentially the same principle but using a different set of ways.

**UPDATE:** Seems like I misread your question, still its easy, here is an example:

```
def label_hide_show(btn,text):
    global hidden
    if hidden:
        label1.config(text=text) # Change to passed text
        label1.pack(side = "top", fill = tk.BOTH, after=btn) # Pack it after the btn
        hidden = False
    else:
        label1.pack_forget()
        hidden=True

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="Get Started", height=3,width=26,bg="White", fg="Black", command=lambda: label_hide_show(btn1,'Label below one'))
btn2 = tk.Button(root, text="Collaborate", height=3,width=26,bg="White", fg="Black", command=lambda: label_hide_show(btn2,'Label below two'))
```

Now the label will be placed `after` the passed button.

Comment: Thank you, 2nd method is working but the 1st button label is showing below the  2nd button but i want the label1 should be visible under button1 and label2 should be visible under button2. @CoolCloud

Comment: @Jung-suk Oh, you should've mentioned it a bit earlier. Gonna need whole revamp to the code

Comment: I did mentioned those points in the explanation. sorry! if its not clear. @CoolCloud

Comment: Thank you. @CoolCloud